# How to host and deploy an ASP.NET web application on a local server

Tags: asp.net, web-applications, deployment, web, web-deployment

I have created a small web application with one page only. Now I want to host and deploy this application on one of our business's server so that anyone can access this small app.

Could please anyone tell me what will be the process as I don't have any previous knowledge or experience of doing this also, what changes I do need to make in my web config and the IIS configuration.

Kind Regards

Comment: There are several ways to do it. Did you Google your question?

Comment: yes i did and I really get lost in them.

Comment: What is your IIS version ? if its 7 , Please find the below article in code project.
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/28693/Deploying-ASP-NET-Websites-on-IIS-7-0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly: [Install IIS](http://www.iis.net/learn/install/installing-iis-7/installing-iis-7-and-above-on-windows-server-2008-or-windows-server-2008-r2) on the server that you want to host your application on

Secondly: [Setup the site in iis](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/323972)

Thirdly: If you have a database connection in your app check that the connection string is updated

Fourthly: Make sure that the relevant port in the firewall is not blocked

Comment: Thank you very much for putting me in right direction. I will give it a try.